# How do you log information using a static method from a class using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, abstract-class, static-methods

This is for a school project. I'm having trouble getting the names from the class to log using a method. I have a class that maakes the monster and another one that extends it.

```js
abstract class genMonster {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public weaknesses: string[],
    public location: string,
    public challenge: number,
    public mortality: boolean = false,
    public safety: number,
  ) {}

  monsterLogger() {
    return this
  }
}

class ghost extends genMonster {
  constructor(id: string, name: string, weaknesses: string[], location: string, challenge: number, mortality: boolean, safety: number, public type: string, public signs: string[]) {
    super(id, name, weaknesses, location, challenge, mortality, safety);
  }

  get info() {
    return console.log(this.name, this.type, this.signs);
  }
}
```

I have the monster objects

```
const Jerry = new ghost("0234", "Jerry", ["soap", "attractive people"], "-74.4835, 171.4803",  3, false, 2, "boring", ["libra", "ectoplasm puddles", "yamaha piano music"]);
const Patricia = new ghost("8765", "Patricia", ["being sent to the corner", "milk and cookies"], "-89.3921, -30.4079",  1, false, 2, "spooky", ["stray drawing supplies", "messy living rooms", "spilled milk"]);
const Lola = new ghost("4569", "Lola", ["makeup remover", "tied shoelaces"], "-61.6134, -90.1008",  10, false, 10, "boss music", ["water tasting like cotton candy", "spontaneous laughing", "socks mysteriously becoming fun and colorful"]);
```

and this is the method I tried but doesn't work

```
class organize extends genMonster{
  constructor(id: string, name: string, weaknesses: string[], location: string, challenge: number, mortality: boolean, safety: number){
    super(id, name, weaknesses, location, challenge, mortality, safety)
  }

  public static getNames(){
    return this.name
  }
}

console.log(organize.getNames());
//logs 'organize'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Exactly what property is `organise.getNames()` supposed to return?

Comment: the name: string of the objects from ghost

Comment: What does `organize` have to do with `ghost` (other than a shared base class)? Should `organize` even be extending `genMonster`?

Comment: What is the _actual problem_ you have been asked to solve?

Comment: I was hoping that by making `organize` it would gather the properties made in `ghost` and return them. I'm not sure if `organize` should extend genmonster, but I tried it to see if it would work

Comment: I was asked to make a abstract class and a extended class to make objects. Then make a static class with a static method that would log the monster names

Answer (score 1):

The `getNames` of `organize` is static and returns the constructor name itself (`"organize"`). Do you intend to get the name of the ghost instances themselves (`Jerry`, `Patricia`, `Lola`)? If so...

```
console.log(Jerry.name, Patricia.name, Lola.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a static method cannot access instance fields, you might need to keep a record of all the names taken by monsters on a static field (`takenNames`) when each monster is created.

Then you could have a static method (`getTakenNames`) that returns `takenNames`

```
abstract class genMonster {
  static takenNames: string[] = [];
  static getTakenNames(): string[] {
    return ghost.takenNames;
  }
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public weaknesses: string[],
    public location: string,
    public challenge: number,
    public mortality: boolean = false,
    public safety: number,
  ) {}

  monsterLogger() {
    return this
  }
}

class ghost extends genMonster {


  constructor(id: string, name: string, weaknesses: string[], location: string, challenge: number, mortality: boolean, safety: number, public type: string, public signs: string[]) {
    super(id, name, weaknesses, location, challenge, mortality, safety);
    ghost.takenNames.push(name);
  }

  get info() {
    return console.log(this.name, this.type, this.signs);
  }
}

const Jerry = new ghost("0234", "Jerry", ["soap", "attractive people"], "-74.4835, 171.4803",  3, false, 2, "boring", ["libra", "ectoplasm puddles", "yamaha piano music"]);
const Patricia = new ghost("8765", "Patricia", ["being sent to the corner", "milk and cookies"], "-89.3921, -30.4079",  1, false, 2, "spooky", ["stray drawing supplies", "messy living rooms", "spilled milk"]);
const Lola = new ghost("4569", "Lola", ["makeup remover", "tied shoelaces"], "-61.6134, -90.1008",  10, false, 10, "boss music", ["water tasting like cotton candy", "spontaneous laughing", "socks mysteriously becoming fun and colorful"]);

console.log(genMonster.getTakenNames())
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=30&pln=7&pc=29#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAg5gUwHYFkB7XSbKBAbwFgAoWhJYyKAV3kKgAp6GEAHFiGQBLWAmEATAFwJmw3JgA0PBgKGiEuYAFtsMuQuU1e-QSLEB3bMADWubOgf7o8zAG0AukZNrzCZISwwBDCxM5Qrt68vhqwABbAyMh4ODK4LNogZFGqZhraHBCJwhAAnjIghITJwLgIALwIAGaJYNg5pupiYMBN2GVpGVlQUQCUlAC%20tDwFJBBkADKEmDhc49TGvFD9LFB1EHHCYDxTNKe0KGgYmHGEkAjYAB7zuBLXeERzZJQ8kMEaRRseAAcjonLIXApPA0EJ4ANy-IohMQ4CAAFVsILBYE4o3CrmhGxM2wguzqNzuEAAdICsbowAjNudNrAmNA2BAOJxJPjDJowbylAgrLZ7I4wILPIp-IF-mEIRE%20fFEskFHpNENsggClAiiIBghKtVrLhpT0%20gb0pktTExGU%20OqDELbbJhJgSJKPOsVLIWA6uJJpVpdNKRXYHG0wNKAkEQsRpcqkil2trCsUymbev1SqNGSYKZAaZjcKD6VSBGA4pxg9hcydpptUeJcE1CLifpsGCSyYwSMaqQFMJwDkcqTXpSOwDTSg6J4cp2A3SQ60zaMzWXMEAApMhQUow%20wWLC3SCcABEAAYAEwAZgALGfpWed1A94-YWewIRgHx32fgtAcAhAAbtg-DYIQfDJGeXgIGeAC0ADsd5UneAAcN4AKzSgAjIhOGoWhF43u%20CA3tKLTIG00pXk%20lSKpg75uGeIggDAf7YOwUFoNopgSBIyRgH%20pQ6MACT8MItSENqLCLrAMErhu9wAArBBEsCSQe2BHgWEDnmhiEAGyYX%20qkuBpwBMWeWSuLIeCIJyCAHGBrJ7GQf7aMIyA2AgtQSIwhA2MIDgwU%208FoQAnFSN4RVeOHSvBN4XqhF6IRFpHxc0rQprRcFgHwVQ2KUVnMMA%204SDAFi2WAfpQcFQlPvSYD7iIwG2VAVTaA1eV8F5yT%20Z53kKYySmIEsqBaTpJ56Wed6YYZ6VPuNlnSsx2iYn6CDbAUoFQH%20ITYP5laENgqCwCFsEIYZBHXfeCURclOEXheaEZReFHZbh71wZU6AyXJVkWME3xFJAtkiECjAQJydRBK8xVPvlxBFPYhCyf4wAsDcrh-l%20sA2Bg2ilKQERo2AyD7lkrKeQozQsHUfmMAEUBNCwyDDQ2Sn9oOnC6VSqIYkCJbYrioxAA)